# Recover Data from old iMac Gen.2 HDD (Maxtor 6L040J2)

Tags: hard-drive, mac, data-recovery, imac

I want to access data of an old iMac Gen2 HDD (40 GB) using Ubuntu 16 and a IDE to SATA adapter (which seems to work: already recovered data of a hdd that didnt spin for 20 years. it sounded as if it would disintegrate in a few seconds but i was lucky :-).

Then I tried to access data of the drive with the Mac partition table. The application Testdisk seemed to detect the Mac partition table. However when I wanted to start a QuickSearch the program seemed to be stuck. After that, i tried to clone the HDD using gnome-disks.

[This is what happens when I try to clone the disk :-/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz35x.png)

The process is super slow and it doesn't seem to read anything meaningful. The "reading speed" startet at 2.5 kbps and increased greatly to 5 kbps after 1 hour :-|. Moreover, my computer needed more than 30 mins to boot with the Mac HDD attached.

Did anyone also encountered and solved this problem? Any suggestions?

Thank you for inputs!

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: Info: The harddrive seems to startup correctly. It makes the expected initilializing noise for about 1-2 seconds. After that the HD remains silent (except for the noise of the spinning disk). I expected to hear the reader head move. It seems like it tries to read the hd like an old fashioned record reader.

Comment: If the data is valuable (and your pockets are deep) send it to a professional data recovery service.

Comment: Thanks GG, but that did not really help (my pockets are super sparse).

Comment: I'm afraid there's no other way.

Comment: Try cloning the block device using (gnu) ddrescue. You can try runninh it many times and it.can use a log file to continue where it left off. You can also try reading backwards.

Comment: Are you certain your machine can read HFS+ ?

Comment: Thank you davidgo. I will certainly try that next weekend. However, I guess it will behave similar.

Thank you very much, Tetsujin! I did not know „HFS+“. Maybe this really IS my problem. Trying to focus on that and report my findings.

Comment: Unix can't read it by default, you would have had to install a specific 'enabler' of some sort. [I'm not very nix-savvy, so idk specifically what you would need.]

Comment: Thank you very much Tetsujin. At least I have an idea whats wrong. Helped me a lot!